# Legendre Polynomials - representation

Tags: spherical-harmonics

Can anybody tell me how I come can rearrange the following formulae into each other:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{l}{2}} (-1)^k {{2l-2k}\choose{l}} {l\choose{k}} x^{l-2k} = \sum_{k=0}^l {l\choose{k}}^2(x-1)^{l-k}(x+1)^k .$$

These are two different representations of the Legendre polynomials, but I can't figure out how to rearrange the left-hand side of the equation into the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Rodrigues' formula
$$P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^nn!}[(x^2-1)^n]^{(n)}$$
we derive
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P_n(x) &= \frac{1}{2^nn!}[(x+1)^n\cdot(x-1)^n]^{(n)}
\\ &= \frac{1}{2^nn!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}[(x+1)^n]^{(k)} \cdot [(x-1)^n]^{(n-k)}
\\ &= \frac{1}{2^nn!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}(x+1)^{n-k} \cdot \frac{n!}{k!}(x-1)^k
\\ &= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2(x+1)^{n-k}(x-1)^k
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P_n(x) &= \frac{1}{2^nn!}[(x^2-1)^n]^{(n)}
\\ &= \frac{1}{2^nn!}[\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}x^{2(n-k)}]^{(n)}
\\ &= \frac{1}{2^nn!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}[x^{2(n-k)}]^{(n)}
\\ &= \frac{1}{2^nn!}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-2k}
\prod_{l=1}^{n}(l+n-2k)
\\ &= \frac{1}{2^nn!}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-2k}
\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}n!
\\ &= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}(-1)^{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-2k}
\end{split}
\end{equation}